# What does *= mean in Python and why is it used over =?

Tags: python

I'm currently going through Codecademy's Python course, and am currently learning functions. In one of the snippets of code they give you, it says:

```
def tax(bill):
    """Adds 8% tax to a restaurant bill."""
    bill *= 1.08
    print "With tax: %f" % bill
    return bill

def tip(bill):
    """Adds 15% tip to a restaurant bill."""
    bill *= 1.15
    print "With tip: %f" % bill
    return bill

meal_cost = 100
meal_with_tax = tax(meal_cost)
meal_with_tip = tip(meal_with_tax)
```

Everything makes complete sense, except for bill *= 1.15 and bill *= 1.08. I know *why* they are what they are, however, I don't understand why they need an asterisk in front of the =. If I were to have written this, I would have just put bill = 1.15 and bill = 1.08. Why would that be wrong?

Comment: It's a shorthand for `bill = bill * 1.15`, so the value of the variable `bill` is multiplied by 1.15 and stored in `bill` again.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `*=` with `=` and running the program? That may give a clue as to why you would use one over the other.

Comment: @ Kevin, good tip, don't know why I didn't think of that. Should have done that first before I posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the same as:

```
bill = bill * 1.15
```

You could also do per example:

```
bill += 1.15
```

Which is the same as:

```
bill = bill + 1.15
```